# Oracle XE and Standard on the same server

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to install both Oracle XE and Standard on the same server? It is for testing purposes. I have XE running at the moment and would like to have both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can install several instances of different or same  versions of RDBMS, different or same  editions on one OS, but in different `$ORACLE_HOME`. Only two XE instances cannot be installed on one server.